# Date String replace

Tags: php

I have a string which is a date, and the format of it is as `2012/04/19`. I want to replace the `/` sign with `-` so it will have the format `2012-04-19`

I tried `str_replace` but it doesn't work.

```
str_replace('2012/04/19','/');
```

Comment: You could read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) . There is really no excuse for not doing that.

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) correctly.

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', '2012/04/19');
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for

```
str_replace("/", "-", "2012/04/19");
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for str_replace is `str_replace(find,replace,string,count)`.

So you'd want to use

```
str_replace('/','-','2012/04/19');
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), the code you need is

```
str_replace("/", "-", "2012/04/19");
```